# spark1.6.2 with scala2.10.6 No TypeTag available

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hue

Im trying to run the KMeans case from [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/ml-clustering.html).

This is my code:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(this.getClass.getName).setMaster("local[10]")//.set("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
// Crates a DataFrame
val dataset: DataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (1, Vectors.dense(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
  (2, Vectors.dense(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)),
  (3, Vectors.dense(0.2, 0.2, 0.2)),
  (4, Vectors.dense(9.0, 9.0, 9.0)),
  (5, Vectors.dense(9.1, 9.1, 9.1)),
  (6, Vectors.dense(9.2, 9.2, 9.2))
)).toDF("id", "features")

// Trains a k-means model
val kmeans = new KMeans()
  .setK(2)
  .setFeaturesCol("features")
  .setPredictionCol("prediction")
val model = kmeans.fit(dataset)

// Shows the result
println("Final Centers: ")
model.clusterCenters.foreach(println)}
```

The Error follow:

```
Information:2016/9/19 0019 下午 3:36 - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 2s 454ms
D:\IdeaProjects\de\src\main\scala\com.te\KMeansExample.scala
    Error:Error:line (18)No TypeTag available for (Int, org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)
    val dataset: DataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
```

**some details:**

**1.** When I run this with spark1.6.2 and scala 2.10.6.it is compile fail and show the Error above.**But** when change the scala version to **2.11.0**  .**it's run OK**.

**2.** I run this code in [Hue](http://gethue.com/) which submit this job to my Cluster by [Livy](https://github.com/cloudera/livy), and my Cluster build with Spark1.6.2 and scala2.10.6

Can anybody help me ? Thanks

[image: hue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not very sure about the cause of this problem but I think that it is because scala reflection in older versions of scala was not able to work out the `TypeTag` of `yet not inferred` function parameters.

In this case,

```
val dataset: DataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (1, Vectors.dense(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
  (2, Vectors.dense(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)),
  (3, Vectors.dense(0.2, 0.2, 0.2)),
  (4, Vectors.dense(9.0, 9.0, 9.0)),
  (5, Vectors.dense(9.1, 9.1, 9.1)),
  (6, Vectors.dense(9.2, 9.2, 9.2))
)).toDF("id", "features")
```

The parameter `Seq((1, Vectors.dense(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)),.....)` is being seen by Scala the first time and hence its type is still not inferred by the system. And hence scala reflection can not work out the associated `TypeTag`.

So... my guess is that if you just move that out.. allow scala to infer the type... it will work.

```
val vectorSeq = Seq(
  (1, Vectors.dense(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
  (2, Vectors.dense(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)),
  (3, Vectors.dense(0.2, 0.2, 0.2)),
  (4, Vectors.dense(9.0, 9.0, 9.0)),
  (5, Vectors.dense(9.1, 9.1, 9.1)),
  (6, Vectors.dense(9.2, 9.2, 9.2))
)

val dataset: DataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(vectorSeq).toDF("id", "features")
```

Comment: I tried but got this issue .    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.$conforms()Lscala/Predef$$less$colon$less;
 at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getSystemProperties(Utils.scala:1582)

Comment: Are you sure that you are using correct version of Spark `"org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.6.2"` as per your scala version `2.10.6` ?

Comment: yes I use  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.6.2"

Comment: Are you submitting this job to your local spark using `spark-submit` script ? If you are then you need to generate a self sufficient jar with all dependencies included. You can use `sbt-assembly` (https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin for that.

Comment: This issue occured while compile the code .so I can't build a Jar to submit .It's so glad that it working after restart the CP and restart IDEA. thank u for ur help